# Python: Opening two CSVs, one path is fine, the other has all backslashes doubled

Tags: python, csv, escaping, filepath, backslash

I'm using csv files to store the large number of variables I need for my program.  I use os.path to define the relative path to the two files and send those paths to a function called get_csv_args that opens the csv and parses the information.  The first path opens fine, but the second path causes an error because the backslashes have all been doubled in the path.  I tried using os.path.normpath but it didn't help.

**Main function**

```
import os
from misc.get_csv_args import get_csv_args
def main():
    server=os.path.abspath('..\..\server_info.csv')
    archive=os.path.abspath('.\CreateDelete_archive_info.csv')
    print server
    print archive
    print str(get_csv_args(server))
    print str(get_csv_args(os.path.normpath(archive)))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**get_csv_args**

```
import csv, os.path
def get_csv_args(filename):
    read_args = csv.reader(open(os.path.normpath(filename), 'rb'))
    args = []
    for row in read_args:
        args = args + row[:2] #Add the first two items in each row to the args list
    args = filter(lambda name: name.strip(), args) #Remove whitespace entries from the list
    return args
```

**Main Output**

> C:\Users\blahblahblah\src\server_info.csv
>
> C:\Users\blahblahblah\src\test_cases\archive\CreateDelete_archive_info.csv
>
> ['server', 'server_name', 'UID', 'user', 'PWD', 'password']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> blahblahblah
>
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\blahblahblah\\src\\test_cases\\archive\\CreateDelete_archive_info.csv'

Comment: Are you sure you have the right path? Using "\\" vs "\" in the path shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you sure the file actually exists?

Comment: @mgilson ...there was a typo in the csv filename and it's working now.  Why are the stupidest simplest errors the hardest to solve?

Comment: @Scart -- Because they're the ones that you assume you've done correctly and so they're the last place you look.

Comment: @mgilson go submit an answer so I can pick it

Comment: Ivc has submitted an answer which has that as a possibility.   You can accept that one.  (I don't mind).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes being doubled is normal behavior, and is not causing your error - it happens because backslash is an escape character (eg, `'\t'` is a tab, but `'\\t'` is a backslash followed by a 't'). This may cause you actual problems down the track, though (eg, a file called '.\thing' will cause horrible breakage), so you should use forward slashes or [raw strings](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for paths.

The most likely thing to be causing your current problem is that the file CreateDelete_archive_info.csv actually doesn't exist. Make sure you have the name and path right - eg, in a command prompt, do:

```
dir C:\Users\blahblahblah\src\test_cases\archive\CreateDelete_archive_info.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried that:

```
archive=os.path.abspath('CreateDelete_archive_info.csv')
```

without the `.\`?